# Full Installation of Ubuntu on a USB Flash Drive from Windows (Without booting into any live usb)

Tags: windows, ubuntu, installation, usb-flash-drive

I am trying to install Ubuntu 19.04 in a 32GB Apacer USB flash drive to boot my computer from the usb and have a full ubuntu running. I just want to run it on my computer.
I know how to install full ubuntu on usb by first creating a live usb and then boot into that live usb and finally install ubuntu on the target usb from that live installation.
But I am interested to know that if there is any way to install full ubuntu on target usb from windows directly without creating or (at least not booting into) any live usb.

I have

- Windows 10 as running OS
- a 32GB Apacer USB Drive

I want to install a full ubuntu 19.04 on 32GB Apacer USB Drive from running Windows 10 without booting into any sort of live installation.

Comment: Well.. maybe a VM would work? Because you will always need to run the live cd to install Ubuntu.

Comment: Actually VM is slow and I want a full bootable installation without using any second usb. 
And installing from live CD forces me to use a second usb and stay on live CD for a significant amount of time.
If there has been any way to install directly into that usb, it would have been very handy.

Comment: Well, I was wrong on that one. Look at this then: https://askubuntu.com/questions/484434/install-ubuntu-without-cd-and-usb-how

Comment: That was helpful. But actually I don't want any dual boot rather a portable full installation.